# Trying to use a swipe.js function on a page

Tags: javascript, html, swipe

I write a webapp using a swipe.js function to swap between the two pages. Problem is that it that i wont swipe trough the first page, if i remove the html code to the first page it will swipe back and forth without problems between the two pages. I cant load the second page when the first page is on. Anyone who knows what the problem could be?

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Share QR</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" /> 
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="article1">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
      <h1>Articles1</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">

<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #062F43;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
}
/* Style the header */
.header {
    background-color: #062F43;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Style the top navigation bar */
.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #062F43;
}

/* Style the topnav links */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #062F43;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* Change color on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #062F43;
    color: white;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #062F43;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media (max-width:1080px) {
    .column {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

#txt {
   color: white; 
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="colunm">
  <h>
    <p>
       <p>

<div class="pie">
    <span class="overlay"></span>
</div>
<style>
.pie {
    margin:  auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 200px 200px 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.pie::after {
    transform: rotate({{temp_x}}deg);      /*  set rotation degree  */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(51,102,255,1) 50%, rgba(255,0,0,1) 100%);
    transform-origin: center bottom;
}
.pie::before {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
.pie .overlay{
    top: 8px;                      /*  match border width  */
    left: 8px;                     /*  match border width  */
    width: calc(100% - 16px);       /*  match border width times 2  */
    height: calc(200% - 10px);      /*  match border width times 2  */
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #062F43;
    z-index: 1;                     /*  move it on top of the pseudo elements  */
}
.pie *,
.pie::before,
.pie::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: inherit;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}   
</style>
</body>
<body>
 <div class="header">
  <h1 style="color: #07969E;"> Hot water left</h1>
  <p id="temp_f" style="color: white;"> 0%</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <h2> <center style="color: #07969E;"> Duration </h2> </center>
    <p> <center style="color: white;">14:42</p> </center>
</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2> <center style="color: #07969E;"> Temperature</h2> </center>
    <p id="temp_c"> <center style="color: white;">0 C°</p> </center>
</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2> <center style="color: #07969E;"> Hot water left</h2> </center>
    <p id="temp_x"> <center style="color: white;">0</p> </center>
</div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2> <center style="color: #07969E;"> Clock</h2> </center>
    <head>
<style="color=white">
<script>

function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}


</script>
</head><body onload="startTime()">

<div> <center id="txt"></div> </center>

 </div>

    </div>
</div>


  <div data-role="page" id="article2">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
      <a href="#article1" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
      <h1>Articles</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
       <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="default" href="css/main.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>

<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #062F43;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
}
/* Style the header */
.header {
    background-color: #062F43;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Style the top navigation bar */
.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #062F43;
}

/* Style the topnav links */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #062F43;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* Change color on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #062F43;
    color: white;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #062F43;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media (max-width:1080px) {
    .column {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

#txt {
   color: white; 
}

</style>
<style>
.button {
    background-color: #07969E;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {background-color: #008a93}

.button:active {
  background-color: #008a93;
  box-shadow:  #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
</style>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="header">
  <h1 style="color: #07969E;"> Hot water left</h1>
  <button class="button">Button</button>

</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <h2> <center style="color: #07969E;"> Duration </h2> 
    <center> <button class="button">Button</button> </center>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2> <center style="color: #07969E;"> Temperature</h2> 
    <center> <button class="button">Button</button> </center>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2> <center style="color: #07969E;"> Hot water left</h2> 
    <center> <button class="button">Button</button> </center>
</div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2> <center style="color: #07969E;"> Clock</h2> 
   <center> <button class="button">Button</button> </center>
<style="color=white">

<div> <center id="txt"></div> 
    </div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="row">
    </div>
    <center div class="column1" align="cente">
            <h2> <center style="color: #07969E;">Live graph</h2>
            <h3> <center style="color: white;"> <a href="index.html" class="transition">Click Me</a> </h3>
            </div>
        <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-role="page" id="article3">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
      <a href="#article1" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
      <h1>Articles</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <p>Article 3</p>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
<script>
$(document).on('swipeleft', '.ui-page', function(event){    
    if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
    {    
        var nextpage = $.mobile.activePage.next('[data-role="page"]');
        // swipe using id of next page if exists
        if (nextpage.length > 0) {
            $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, {transition: "slide", reverse: false}, true, true);
        }
        event.handled = true;
    }
    return false;         
});

$(document).on('swiperight', '.ui-page', function(event){     
    if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
    {      
        var prevpage = $(this).prev('[data-role="page"]');
        if (prevpage.length > 0) {
            $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {transition: "slide", reverse: true}, true, true);
        }
        event.handled = true;
    }
    return false;            
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got your markup mixed up quite a tad there. There's multiple `<head>` and `<body>` tags while [the standard only allows one of each](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.1).

> An HTML 4 document is composed of three parts:
>
> 1. a line containing HTML version information,
> 2. a declarative header section (delimited by the HEAD element),
> 3. a body, which contains the document's actual content. The body may be implemented by the BODY element or the FRAMESET element.

You will need to reduce your code to a valid HTML document to make this work. It looks like you copied the source of multiple individual files into one, you have to combine the different elements, though.

- Start off with the basic HTML structure
- Copy all elements from the individual `head`parts into the `<head>`
- Copy all `<style>` tags to the `<head>`
- Copy all markup of each individual page into the `<body>` element
- Copy all `<script>` tags to the `<body>`

While you do this, make sure to get rid of redundant code. The style tags look fairly close to each other, for example.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this. Should <p> and <h> also be put into body then? I have taken parts of others codes and mixed it up to my own :)

Comment: @SveinRikardSemb sorry for not getting back. Yes, as the `body` of the document [contains all of its content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#edef-BODY).